# How do I get the current path of a project in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to find out the path of a current project in a subfolder?

If I have for instance something like:

```
/
    main.py
    /utils
        utilities.py
    /foo
        foo.py
        /foo/bar
           bar.py
```

While coding in `/foo/foo.py` or in `/foo/bar/bar.py` I want to include the "utilities" module located at `/utils/utilities.py` How can I do this by calling some sort of relative path to the project and then just import this helper module?

I am able to retrieve the path of a file being executed with:

```
os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile( inspect.currentframe() ))[0]))
```

But what I need is the relative or absolute path of the current project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Intra-package references](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)?

Comment: possible dupicate; take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6098238/1107807

Comment: I got this working with an example provided here:
cmd_subfolder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.split(inspect.getfile( inspect.currentframe() ))[0],"../../utils/")))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the path if you set your project up as a package, which in this case should be as simple as putting an empty `__init__.py` into each folder:

```
/src
    __init__.py
    main.py
    foo/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        /bar
        __init__.py
        bar.py
    util/
        __init__.py
        utilities.py
```

Now, `main.py`, `foo.py` and `bar.py` can import your `utilities` module via a simple:

```python
from util import utilities
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this working with an example provided here:

```
cmd_subfolder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.split(inspect.getfile( inspect.currentframe() ))[0],"../../utils/")))
```